# Single query to get date and flag the date as enabled

Tags: mysql

I have a list of dates:

```
1/1/2011
2/2/2011
3/3/2011
4/4/2011
5/5/2011
```

and i need to take out "x" number of dates and mark it as enabled.

=> Get the  2 oldest, then i need

```
1/1/2011 - 0 (enabled)
2/2/2011 - 0
3/3/2011 - 1 (disabled)
4/4/2011 - 1
5/5/2011 - 1
```

=> Get the 3 oldest, then i need

```
1/1/2011 - 0 (enabled)
2/2/2011 - 0
3/3/2011 - 0
4/4/2011 - 1  (disabled)
5/5/2011 - 1
```

I can get like this:

```
select * from table order by date_column limit 2; - for 2 entries.

select * from table order by date_column limit 3; - for 3 entries.
```

But how do in a single query i can add 1 or 0 based on the date values? Is there any way this can be done in a single query?

Comment: Do you want the 0 or 1 just to appear in the select, or updating a different column?

Comment: Just as a part of output returned through select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  T1.DateColumn,
   Case when Isnull(T2.DateColumn) 
    then 1
    Else 0 end 
  as disabled
 from table T1 left outer join
  (select dateColumn from table 
   order by date_column asc limit 3) T2
  On t1.dateColumn =t2.DateColumn
 Order by t1.datecolumn asc
```

Comment: Looks close, but it returns 1 to all the values, it should not return 1 for first 3, should return 0. (for enabled).

Comment: @shArpeye500 sure? Exec only sub query in order to identify 3 oldest dates, then execute query and search for this dates. See you.

Answer (score 1):

This query works assuming are dates are unique:

```
SELECT
    A.date_column,ISNULL(B.date_column) enabled
FROM
    `table` LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT date_column FROM `table` ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 3) B
    USING (date_column);
```

If dates are not unique in the table, then try this query:

```
SELECT
    A.date_column,
    IF(ISNULL(B.date_column)=0,'0 (enabled)','1 (disabled)') status
FROM
    `table` A LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT date_column
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date_column FROM `table` ORDER BY date_column) AA
        LIMIT 3
    ) B
    USING (date_column);
```

Give it a Try !!!

This time I tried it with your data:

```
use junk
drop table `table`;
create table `table` (date_column DATE);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
('2011-01-01'),
('2011-02-02'),
('2011-03-03'),
('2011-04-04'),
('2011-05-05');
SELECT * FROM `table`;
SELECT

    A.date_column,
    IF(ISNULL(B.date_column)=0,'0 (enabled)','1 (disabled)') status
FROM
    `table` A LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT date_column FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT date_column FROM `table` ORDER BY date_column) AA
    LIMIT 3) B
USING (date_column);
```

Here is the output:

```
mysql> use junk
Database changed
mysql> drop table `table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create table `table` (date_column DATE);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
    -> ('2011-01-01'),('2011-02-02'),('2011-03-03'),
    -> ('2011-04-04'),('2011-05-05');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `table`;
+-------------+
| date_column |
+-------------+
| 2011-01-01  |
| 2011-02-02  |
| 2011-03-03  |
| 2011-04-04  |
| 2011-05-05  |
+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->
    ->     A.date_column,
    ->     IF(ISNULL(B.date_column)=0,'0 (enabled)','1 (disabled)') status
    -> FROM
    ->     `table` A LEFT JOIN
    ->     (SELECT date_column FROM
    ->         (SELECT DISTINCT date_column FROM `table` ORDER BY date_column) AA
    LIMIT 3) B
    ->     LIMIT 3) B
    -> USING (date_column);
+-------------+--------------+
| date_column | status       |
+-------------+--------------+
| 2011-01-01  | 0 (enabled)  |
| 2011-02-02  | 0 (enabled)  |
| 2011-03-03  | 0 (enabled)  |
| 2011-04-04  | 1 (disabled) |
| 2011-05-05  | 1 (disabled) |
+-------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, tried the second one and i get

Error Code : 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias.

I use 1 table.

Comment: Added a AA after (SELECT DISTINCT date_column FROM table ORDER BY date_column)

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN table_name B
USING (date_column)'

I don't think this is related to mysql version, mine is mysql 5.2, i tried the query didn't execute.

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra comma before the LEFT JOIN. I edited it again. Try it now !!!

Comment: Thanks, no problem.

I need this as output:

1/1/2011 - 0 (enabled)
2/2/2011 - 0
3/3/2011 - 1 (disabled)
4/4/2011 - 1
5/5/2011 - 1


but i get

1/1/2011 - 0 (enabled)
2/2/2011 - 0

if i run this query. In other words i need all the dates and a flag for each record.

LIMIT 3, it can be 2 or 5 anything.

Comment: Updated my answer to display 'enabled' and 'disabled'

Comment: Thanks Rolando, but i marked danihp's response as answered, he overtook you in a couple of secs.